# Stash files not in commit before committing?

Tags: git

I have a number of unstaged files, some of which are tracked and some untracked. I also have a single staged file which is the only file I want to commit, but I dont want to lose any of my changes locally to the other files.

Before I commit the staged file do I need to stash my other files?

Comment: By other files do you mean only your tracked files or both tracked and untracked files?.

Comment: @mig-25foxbat I mean both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to stash any files in this situation. Committing is not a destructive action in git.

Files that you have staged will be included in the commit and all unstaged and untracked files will remain exactly as they are.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can stash your code to see the difference in behavior before and after adding your code, without losing the code on your working directory and another case is when  you want to change branch so you stash your code in order not to lose it after changing branch.

So if you stash before committing , there will be nothing to commit!